# Grid bag layout not displaying the way I want

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

So I have 6 panels, all of them used a grid layout.
And I put them together using gridbaglayout, here is the design I wanted

[image: layout]

Turn out it became a total mess
The "second" panel became much further away to the right
The third panel is squeezed a lot to the left and it was a disaster.
Here is my code for the gridbag layout

```
    c.gridx = 0; c.gridy = 0;
    add (first,c); 

    c.gridx = 2; //so that the second panel starts from the center and is divided evenly with the first panel
    add(second,c);

    c.gridx = 0; c.gridy = 1;
    add(third,c);

    c.gridx = 1; 
    add(fourth,c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    add(fifth,c);

    c.gridx = 3;
    add(sixth,c);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

As you wrote `c.gridx = 0 and c.gridy = 0`, you forgot to specify how many columns you want this `JPanel` to occupy. In order to specify that, you should be using `c.gridwidth = 2`, which tells the layout that this `JPanel` needs space for two columns.

To get an output like this:

[image: GRIDBAGLAYOUTEXAMPLE]

Here is a small working example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968853/two-jpanels-in-jframe-one-under-other
public class GridBagLayoutExample
{
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977017/grid-bag-layout-not-displaying-the-way-i-want
    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 0.5;
        gbc.weighty = 0.2;

        JPanel topLeftPanel = new JPanel();
        topLeftPanel.setOpaque(true);
        topLeftPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        contentPane.add(topLeftPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;

        JPanel topRightPanel = new JPanel();
        topRightPanel.setOpaque(true);  
        topRightPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.add(topRightPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.25;
        gbc.weighty = 0.8;

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.setOpaque(true);
        firstPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        contentPane.add(firstPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();
        secondPanel.setOpaque(true);
        secondPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN.darker());
        contentPane.add(secondPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;

        JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel();
        thirdPanel.setOpaque(true);
        thirdPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.add(thirdPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;

        JPanel fourthPanel = new JPanel();
        fourthPanel.setOpaque(true);
        fourthPanel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        contentPane.add(fourthPanel, gbc);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(200, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBagLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @trashgod : Thankx for the edit, now it makes more sense. Previously, my English seems like is not making that sense. When must turned into should, that's when I realized my English is really not that good in explaining things :-) Thankx again :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is (another) alternative nested layout.  Panels 3 through 6 will get extra height, the extra width will be divided evenly amongst all 6 panels.

[image: SixPanelNested]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class SixPanelNested {

    SixPanelNested() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        gui.setBorder(new TitledBorder("BorderLayout()"));

        JPanel north = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
        north.setBorder(new TitledBorder("GridLayout(1,0)"));
        gui.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        for (int ii=1; ii<3; ii++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel("Panel " + ii);
            l.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            north.add(l);
        }

        JPanel south = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
        south.setBorder(new TitledBorder("GridLayout(1,0)"));
        gui.add(south);
        for (int ii=3; ii<7; ii++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel("Panel " + ii);
            l.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            south.add(l);
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SixPanelNested();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar enough with the `GridBagLayout` to quickly spot what you can improve to your code to fix this. But another approach might be possible, using nested `BorderLayout`s.

Panels 'first', 'third' and 'fourth' can be placed inside one `JPanel` `A`with a `BorderLayout` in the `NORTH`, `WEST` and `EAST` respectively. The same can be done for the panels 'second', 'fifth' and 'sixth' in a JPanel `B`.

Then you group those 2 panels (`A` and `B`) in another panel with a `BorderLayout` in the `WEST` and `EAST`

Comment: *"Then you group those 2 panels (`A` and `B`) in another panel with a.."* `GridLayout(1,0)` if I understand your `A` & `B` correctly and the requirement is for them to stretch to the available width.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response guys, but I am a little curious about the solution using the same gridbag layout.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

`c.gridwidth = 2;`

Before adding the FIRST and SECOND panels, then set gridwidth back to 1 before adding the others.
Alternatively you could separate them further as suggested above. You could use two FlowLayouts for each row, and add those two to another panel with a BorderLayout with NORTH/SOUTH.

Comment: Edit : I think it fixed the first and second panel, thanks Tom