# GridBagLayout biger panel over another panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Can anyone give me an example of how to put a panel of a determined size over another panel of determined size inside a JFrame?

i mean something like this

```
-------------------
|                 |
|       Panel 1   |      
|                 | 
|                 |
-------------------
|                 |
|      Panel 2    |                                         
-------------------
```

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc he is (presumably) adding a panel to a panel.

Comment: @DaftPunk, that is for the OP to express clearly. He could be trying to use a CardLayout type situation where two panels occupy the same space but only one is visible at a time), or maybe he is trying to paint a semi-transparent panel on top of another panel, or maybe just add a child panel to a parent panel. As I stated earlier it is up to the OP to post a clear question so we don't spend time guessing.

Comment: sorry i explaned my self in the wrong way ill edit

Comment: [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is your friend in this case, some related examples can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10979659/1057230), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11166903/1057230) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14757600/1057230). As requested special link to how [**accepting an answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). There are several you can choose from. `BorderLayout` may be the easiest as it does automatic resizing of the width.

Note that you should not be hardcoding sizes. Let the layout manager determine the size.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) Swing Component.

I would suggest for you to read [How to use Split Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html), and the layout manager links from camickr's answer